# Replace column values based on column in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to replace some column values in a df based on column in another data frame
This is the head of the first df:

```
 df1
A tibble: 253 x 2
      id sum_correct
    <int>       <dbl>
 1 866093          77
 2 866097          95
 3 866101          37
 4 866102          65
 5 866103          16
 6 866104          72
 7 866105          99
 8 866106          90
 9 866108          74
10 866109          92
```

and some sum_correct need to be replaced by the correct values in another df using the id to trigger the replacement

```
df 2 
A tibble: 14 x  2
     id sum_correct
    <int>       <dbl>
 1 866103          61
 2 866124          79
 3 866152          85
 4 867101          24
 5 867140          76
 6 867146          51
 7 867152          56
 8 867200          50
 9 867209          97
10 879657          56
11 879680          61
12 879683          58
13 879693          77
14 881451          57
```

how I can achieve this in R studio? thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a `left_join` and then use `coalesce`:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by = "id", suffix = c("_1", "_2")) %>%
  mutate(sum_correct_final = coalesce(sum_correct_2, sum_correct_1))
```

The new column `sum_correct_final` contains the value from `df2` if it exists and from `df1` if a corresponding entry from `df2` does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can make an *update join* using `match` to find where `id` matches and remove non matches (`NA`) with `which`:

```
idx <- match(df1$id, df2$id)
idxn <- which(!is.na(idx))
df1$sum_correct[idxn]  <- df2$sum_correct[idx[idxn]]
df1
       id sum_correct
1  866093          77
2  866097          95
3  866101          37
4  866102          65
5  866103          61
6  866104          72
7  866105          99
8  866106          90
9  866108          74
10 866109          92
```