# Replace column values using key value dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

*I must imagine this question is not unique, but I was struggling with which words to search for so if this is redundant please point me to the post!*

I have a dataframe

```
test <- data.frame(x = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))

  x
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
```

And I'd like to replace SOME of the values using a separate data frame

```
metadata <- data.frame(
  a = c("c", "d"),
  b = c("REPLACE_1", "REPLACE_2"))
```

Resulting in:

```
  x
1 a
2 b
3 REPLACE_1
4 REPLACE_2
5 e
```

Comment: Have a look at [Replace column values based on column in another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59134813/10488504), [Merge dataframes of different sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34438349/10488504) or [Update join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52170570/10488504).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing your data with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` and using `dplyr` and `stringr`, you can do:

```
test %>%
 mutate(x = str_replace_all(x, setNames(metadata$b, metadata$a)))

          x
1         a
2         b
3 REPLACE_1
4 REPLACE_2
5         e
```

Or using the basic idea from @Sotos:

```
test %>%
 mutate(x = pmax(x, metadata$b[match(x, metadata$a, nomatch = x)], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 3):

A base R solution using `match` + `replace`

```
test <- within(test,x <- replace(as.character(x),match(metadata$a,x),as.character(metadata$b)))
```

such that

```
> test
          x
1         a
2         b
3 REPLACE_1
4 REPLACE_2
5         e
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do,

```
test$x[test$x %in% metadata$a] <- na.omit(metadata$b[match(test$x, metadata$a)])

 #         x
#1         a
#2         b
#3 REPLACE_1
#4 REPLACE_2
#5         e
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach, though I presume there are shorter ones:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
  left_join(metadata, by = c("x" = "a")) %>%
  mutate(b = coalesce(b, x))

#  x         b
#1 a         a
#2 b         b
#3 c REPLACE_1
#4 d REPLACE_2
#5 e         e
```

(Note, I have made the data types match by loading `metadata` as character, not factors:

```
metadata <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F,
  a = c("c", "d"),
  b = c("REPLACE_1", "REPLACE_2"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match` to make this *update join*.

```
i <- match(metadata$a, test$x)
test$x[i]  <- metadata$b
# test
#          x
#1         a
#2         b
#3 REPLACE_1
#4 REPLACE_2
#5         e
```

Or:

```
i <- match(test$x, metadata$a)
j <- !is.na(i)
test$x[j]  <- metadata$b[i[j]]
test
#          x
#1         a
#2         b
#3 REPLACE_1
#4 REPLACE_2
#5         e
```

Data:

```
test <- data.frame(x = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
metadata <- data.frame(
  a = c("c", "d"),
  b = c("REPLACE_1", "REPLACE_2"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```